# How to start a Laravel project in eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, laravel

I have installed Laravel in windows 7 apache 2.4. I installed it with the following steps:

1. Create folder named new_project under `apache24/htdocs` (which is also eclipse workspace folder);
2. Then I insalled Laravel by command : `composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist`
3. The laravel is installed in `C:\apache24\htdocs\new_project\laravel\`
4. I have also download a laravel_helper_function.php and include it in Eclipse PHP include path. It make the Laravel namespace visible.

Then I tried a simple program, and tried to debug it.

```
<?php

  App::isLocal();
  phpinfo();
  echo("hello");
  echo("hello");

?>
```

I set a breakpoint in

```
 App::isLocal();
```

However, the line does not executed and stop responding. I doubt that although I have the helper function that makes me to use laravel namespace. However, eclipse seems do not know where to call the Laravel function? What step do I missed? I am new to Laravel. And I have search the internet. Seems no answer.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I put it simple, the question is how to add Laravel library to Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. Just include these two file in laravel installed folder to index.php, then I can debug it. I found it after I read the documentation in Laravel website
carefully again.

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/start.php';
```

then the app can run.

```
$app->run();
```

Thanks so much